# choose the minimum set of elements that uniquely identifies all sets

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I have a total of m elements distributed in N sets, each represented by 1 to k < m elements. My goal is to choose the minimum number of elements needed to uniquely identify all N sets.

For example: suppose there are 4 sets (A, B, C, D) containing 6 elements (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

A: {1, 3, 5, 6} 
B: {2, 4, 5, 6} 
C: {1, 2, 4, 6} 
D: {1, 4, 5}

checking each set for 3 would yield truth values of 1, 0, 0 ,0 for sets A, B, C, D
checking each set for 2 would yield truth values of 0, 1, 1, 0 for sets A, B, C, D
checking each set for 1 would yield truth values of 1, 0, 1, 1 for sets A, B, C, D

thus after checking 3 elements, each set is represented by a unique truth table (A: {1, 0, 1}; B: {0, 1, 0,} etc.). The minimum number of elements needed is thus 3, and the elements are 1, 2, and 3. How would i generalize this approach to m elements and N sets?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: In which context do you need this?

Comment: i am not sure how detailed an answer you're looking for, but broadly speaking it's a bioinformatics problem.

Comment: And (on another note): Could you specify your problem? While in your example you specify  the sets, the problem you formulate only gives us the number N and m. So are you looking for a number k such that, regardless of the concrete sets, k elements will suffice? Can you guarantee that no two sets are identic?

Comment: If each set were a singleton you would have to use as many elements as sets (or one less than that, depending on context and use).

Comment: OK so i am looking for a minimal set of elements of size j < m that uniquely identifies all N sets using the approach mentioned in the original post. Yes i can guarantee that no two sets are identical, and no sets are singletons.

Comment: It will depend on the particular sets, but assuming there are no duplicate sets then you need at least $\log_2(N)$ and no more than $N-1$.  In your example with $N=4$ these are $2$ and $3$, and it turns out $3$ is correct, but it would have been $2$ if say $C=\{1,2,4\}$ and you had looked at elements $2$ and $6$

Comment: Thanks. Log2(N) would be great, but is there a general solution to this problem? Or a direction I can look into to get to a general solution?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_{N\times m} = (a)_{i,j}$ be a binary matrix where $j$ belongs to the set $i$ if $a_{i,j}=1$. This gives a bijection between the binary matrices and your instances.
Then your problem is equivalent to find the smallest subset of columns that keeps each row distinct. This problem is known as the "Distinct vectors problem", and is known to be $\mathcal{NP}$-Hard, even for binary matrices.